# shutdown doesn't work

Tags: shutdown, lvm, firmware

I've been experiencing a problem where my machine doesn't want to shut down properly, forcing me to hold down the power button for a force shutdown. It happens both with commands and when pressing the button in the interface. Strangely enough, when i run `sudo reboot`, it seems to work fine. ('seems' because the behaviour is a bit inconsistent so it might stop working as well)

I've seem a few people mention 'nvmetad' as a possible cause, but it doesn't seem to be enabled in the first place. That is:

`systemctl list-unit-files | grep lvm` only yields the following:

```
lvm2-lvmpolld.service                                      static          -
lvm2-monitor.service                                       enabled         enabled
lvm2-pvscan@.service                                       static          -
lvm2.service                                               masked          enabled
lvm2-lvmpolld.socket                                       enabled         enabled
```

The whole thing started happening after a bunch of updates, including a bios update. I'm thinking that should be the cause, but it's unclear to me what I can do about it.

My machine is a Lenovo Thinkpad p50
I'm running pop!-os 21.04

Comment: I was always against BIOS updates, have seen too many problems arise in decades. Any way to roll back to the previous BIOS ? I think your problem lies there and Lenovo has only tested their update on Windows editions.

Comment: I got it working again by reverting to the last kernel. (under pop-os the old kernel is always stored). Not quite a permanent solution but I'm thinking I could go back to the current with some future update.